# How to prevent AutoPostBack from resetting my page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I am building a page that includes some components that are static on the page (dropdowns, buttons, a table to hold them in), but one table cell is filled with variably generated CheckBoxes. When a button is pressed, the code for the page calculates what checkboxes to place and creates a new `CheckBox` object for each one needed and then adds it to an existing Div on the page.

I am trying to trigger some code to run when any of these are checked or unchecked, but `checkBoxName.CheckedChanged += cbCheckedChanged` wasn't working. I researched and found two suggestions: enabling viewstate and enabling autopostback.

`checkBoxName.EnableViewState = true;` seems to make no difference, nor did `checkBoxName.ViewStateMode = ViewStateMode.Enabled;` or any variations on that i tried. `checkBoxName.AutoPostBack = true;` did SOMETHING, but it's not allowing it to run the code I want. I think that's because it doesn't reach that point because of the next problem:

With `AutoPostBack = true`, whenever I check or uncheck a box, `cbCheckedChanged`is not being executed, and the entire page is reloading, resetting back to it's initial state, therefore removing the checkboxes completely from the table.

How can I fix these problems, or at least where might I start looking?

Edit:

This is where the checkboxes are created:

```
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
cb.Text = CBName;
cb.EnableViewState = true;
cb.ViewStateMode = ViewStateMode.Enabled;
cb.AutoPostBack = true;
cb.CheckedChanged += CBCheckedChanged;
```

and this is where CBCheckedChanged is:

```
private void CBCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
\\Stuff
}
```

When I use breakpoints to step through it, it never reaches CBCheckedChanged. I have tried every possible combination of commenting out and leaving in the AutoPostBack, ViewStateMode, and EnableViewState lines.

Page_Load is currently empty, nothing runs until the user hits a button.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you are using checkBoxName.CheckedChanged += cbCheckedChanged and AutoPostBack = true together?  If you set a breakpoint in the page_load event and step through after you've checked the checkbox it doesn't go into your event handler?

Comment: When using postback, you'd need to have your code in the Page_Load event handler encapsulated inside of this: `If Not IsPostBack Then ...` to ensure that this initialization code only runs on the first load of the page.

Comment: The event will not be executed unless you have recreated all the controls, and a post will always reconstruct your page as it sends a new page, if you want partial updates use an UpdatePanel.

Comment: Can you post the markup and code behind that you're trying to get working?

Comment: @Gusman, I do't know where to start on that, do i put the div i am putting the checkboxes in in an updatepanel? do i just everything else in one? the checkbox by itself?
What i want is the contents of the page NOT to change except the one checkbox being checked, but to trigger the running of CBCheckedChanged

Comment: @Seano666 Yes, see my edit, and it does not ever go to the eventhandler, it just resets the page.

Comment: A postback will send the content of your page to the server and your server will send a new page, so all the content will be reset, if you wrap the checkboxes (and all the controls which might change when the check is clicked) on an UpdatePanel the page will not be reset as it will not be reloaded, it will use ajax to send/receive data. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Where in your code (which method) are the dynamically generated Checkboxes created?

Comment: there's a ` public void checkCoursesDegree(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { STUFF } that is triggerred by a button onClick

Comment: @Gusman: I put the checkboxes and everything else that was dynamically generated in an UpdatePanel(which then made me add a scriptmanager before it would run), but got the same results.

Comment: Using and UpdatePanel does not solve any problem on its own. All it does is to hide a page reload for the user. Even when you are using an UpdatePanel an entire page life cycle is executed back on the server side when an event is triggered. Basically what happens is that ASP.NET then checks which part of the page changed and only updates those for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ViewState** is by default enabled for server side controls. You don't have to tinker around with ViewState to solve your problem. ViewState is basically used to restore the state of a control after a postback happens. For example readding all entries to a `ListBox` control. This is why most control population code is within such a construct in the `Page_Load` method.

```
private void Page_Load()
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        // populate controls here
    }
}
```

ViewState is a very misunderstood concept. There is a [great article here](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate) that goes into it in detail. But as I said, for your problem ViewState is not a concern.

**To solve your problem:**

The problem in your case is that the triggered button is creating the `CheckBox` controls, but when the page is reloaded, because of the `CheckedChanged` event of these controls, the next page life cycle has no clue of the `CheckBox` controls that were placed on the page in the previous page life cycle. Dynamic controls need to be generated for every page life cycle!

So what I would do is create a method that:

- creates the `CheckBox` controls and
- sets `AutoPostback = true` for them and
- sets the event handler for `CheckedChanged`

Let's call this method `AddDynamicCheckBoxes()`. Now you need to call this method in the `Page_Load` event of your `Page` when the button was already pressed and also in the event handler of the button's click event. You could do this like follows:

```
private void Page_Load()
{
    if (ViewState["button_was_clicked"] != null)
    {
        AddDynamicCheckBoxes();
    }
}

private void Button_OnClick()
{
    AddDynamicCheckBoxes();
    ViewState["button_was_clicked"] = true;
}
```

Comment: Upvote for understanding this tricky stuff and giving a good explanation

Comment: This did fix the problem of the page resetting...so thank you for that...unfortunately though, I'm still not triggering CheckedChanged for some reason.

Comment: Update: It works! I don't know the exact problem, but apparently it had something to do with me trying to assign the CheckBoxes non-unique IDs accidentally? Not sure why that happened, or why it wasn't giving an error before, or why it caused this particular problem, but i got an error when i tried to refresh the page after checking a box, saying something about nonunique id's, and commented out the section that assigned an id, and the whole thing started working.

Comment: Glad I could help.